# overpass api too many requests

Tags: python, overpass-api

I want to get specific users data from OpenStreetMap. I use Overpass API, but I get an error:

> overpy.exception.DataIncomplete: ('Data incomplete try to improve the
> query to resolve the missing data', 'Resolve missing nodes is
> disabled')

The solution from [here](https://python-overpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example.html) says to get nodes by the get_nodes(resolve_missing=True) function and parameter, however now I get the error

> overpy.exception.OverpassTooManyRequests: Too many requests

Code:

```
api = overpy.Overpass()
result = api.query("[out:json];way(user:'{}')({}, {}, {}, {})(changed:'{}T{}Z', '{}T{}Z');out;".format(user, max_coords['south'], max_coords['west'], max_coords['north'], max_coords['east'], start_date, start_time, end_date, end_time))
for way in result.ways:
    way_nodes_list = []
    nodes = way.get_nodes(resolve_missing=True)
    for node in nodes:
        way_nodes_list.append((float(node.lon), float(node.lat)))
```

Comment: Well, obviously you exceeded your "contingent" of request per time frame. Slow down and try again in half an hour.

Comment: @Erik  Thank you. I will do that. I thought it had something to do with changing the way I requested nodes.